# Sharepoint 2016 .iqy file keep asking for login

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, authentication, login, export-to-excel

One of my client is using sharepoint 2016 and he wants to export the sharepoint 2016 list to excel, so From couple of days, i'm facing issue of exporting sharepoint 2016 list to excel using there export to excel feature. It's working fine with downloading the .iqy file, but when I open it, it prompted me to sharepoint login page, till now it's all good. It open the client login page that they use to login the user into sharepoint. The user can login with two ways, one is window authentication for there employees and one is form based. so when i try to login with my credentials, it keep opening the login page again and again.

I tried to open it using from web feature of excel where we need to give URL to it, and in that when login using organizational account, it open the same login page and i login again, it logged me in and when i press connect it giving me error the **credential are invalid**, but it says you are signed in, then i click on anonymous user and it keeps me import the list to excel using anonymous login. Can anyone help me out with this how i can make it work with .iqy file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following steps to troubleshooting this issue.

1.Open Registry Editor.

2.Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Microsoft > Office > 16.0 > Common > Identity

3.Right click > New > DWORD (32 bit) value > type Value name: EnableADAL > set Value data: 0

4.Restart the PC

For Reference: [Can not open the Sharepoint List (.iqy) Export file, stuck in a continuous loop to login to Sharepoint when using proper credentials](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/can-not-open-the-sharepoint-list-iqy-export-file/215eac6b-9ced-4b06-a342-d3a794820589)